# How to handle finding a better duplicate; Updating close votes

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Just ran into a question that was a slightly complicated duplicate: [How to call a function given a string of that function's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677249/how-to-call-a-function-given-a-string-of-that-functions-name).

I looked at the question, and could pretty clearly tell that it was a duplicate. However, it was tough for me to lock down exactly which duplicate it was. I found this question: [Python string to attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253966/python-string-to-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1), which was clearly a duplicate and first marked that.

However, after a little bit more googling around I found this question: [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name), which was clearly a better match for the duplicate.

I then realized that there's no way of revising my close vote. I wanted to update the duplicate I marked, but my only options were to retract my vote (obviously not the right move). I ended up deleting the auto-comment and making a new one, but this is clearly not the right way to handle things.

I suppose I should have been a bit more diligent in marking it the first time, but the search while marking duplicates doesn't work very well. I spent about 5 minutes googling for the best I could find, and it was only randomly half an hour later that I found the new duplicate.

So, my question is: why can't I update a close vote? I'm now stuck in the position where I feel I've voted incorrectly, but my only recourse is to make my vote even worse (by retracting it), while having the ability to update my close vote seems like a great solution.

I can't be the first person to think this though. What's the reason for not allowing me to update my close vote, and is there any better way to fix the issue I've got?